# Adding waveguide elements to Circuitikz diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

In literature, generalized waveguide connections to other circuits are represented similar to Z_in and Z_out in figure a) which is from [M.S Khalil et al. 2012](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.3117.pdf)(1). Does Circuitikz have a similar element? How would you go about creating such an element to add to a diagram?

[image]

(1) M. S. Khalil, M. J. A. Stoutimore, F. C. Wellstood, and K. D. Osborn , "An analysis method for asymmetric resonator transmission applied to superconducting devices", Journal of Applied Physics 111, 054510 (2012) https://doi.org/10.1063/1.3692073

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Although those are not really standard symbols, you have `tline` and `tlinestub` (see the manual at page 126 and following, about RF components; there is an example also on how to change relative size). Try it and if you have problems, add the code to the question and we'll try to help.

Comment: Note that circuitiiz **is** tikz, so you can always combine a shaded cylinder and a schematic.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360412/drawing-cylinder-in-3d-plane for an example of a shaded cylinder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get you started:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \tikzset{bare tl/.style={tlineshape,
        circuitikz/bipoles/tline/bare=true,
        circuitikz/RF/fill=gray!20}}
    \draw (0,0) node[bare tl, label=90:$Z_{in}$](A){};
    \draw (A.right) -| ++(1,1) to[L=$L_1$, f>^=$V_{in}$] ++(2,0)
        (A.bottom right) -- ++(1,0) node[ground]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

More info in the [manual](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/92df9ffea0e5b6822f9e1d71e10b9c21d7c3b5e9/circuitikzmanualgit.pdf#97), as ever...

Comment: Thank you, this is a very useful answer! Unfortunately, in my document 'circuitikz/bipoles/tline/bare' is not found and 'A.bottom right' isn't a known function (Neither is 'bottom' or 'top' in general. Any idea what might cause these errors?

Comment: You probably have an old version of `circuitikz`, you need 1.6.1. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524328/i-need-to-use-a-different-version-of-circuitikz-how-can-i-do-that