# How can fill between two cylinders to create holes in cylinders?

Tags: tikz-3dplot

I see question at here [creating a small cylinder within a larger cylinder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160651/creating-a-small-cylinder-within-a-larger-cylinder) to creat a hole in cylinders. I tried

```
\documentclass[border=1mm,12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc,backgrounds,patterns}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\begin{document}
    \def\myr{1.5}
    \def\myR{3}
    \def\h{5}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{80}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=1,line cap=butt,line join=round]

    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
    \coordinate (A) at (\tdplotmainphi:\myr);
    \coordinate (B) at (\tdplotmainphi+180:\myr);
    \coordinate (C) at (\tdplotmainphi:\myR);
    \coordinate (D) at (\tdplotmainphi+180:\myR);
%\draw circle [radius=\myR];
\draw[dashed] circle [radius=\myr];
\draw[dashed] (\tdplotmainphi:\myR) arc(\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi+180:\myR);
    \draw[thick] (\tdplotmainphi:\myR)  arc(\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi-180:\myR);    
    \end{scope}
    %
\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=\h]
\draw[thick] circle [radius=\myr];
\draw[thick] circle [radius=\myR];
    \coordinate (A') at (\tdplotmainphi:\myr);
\coordinate (B') at (\tdplotmainphi+180:\myr);
\coordinate (C') at (\tdplotmainphi:\myR);
\coordinate (D') at (\tdplotmainphi+180:\myR);
\end{scope}
    \foreach \X in {A,B} \draw[dashed] (\X) -- (\X');
    \foreach \X in {C,D} \draw[thick] (\X) -- (\X');
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

I cann't fill two cylinders to create holes in cylinders. How can I fill it?

Can I get like this picture?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Like this?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/205120/15036

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[border=1mm,12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\begin{document}
\def\myr{1.5}
\def\myR{3}
\def\h{5}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{80}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=1,line cap=butt,line join=round]
 \draw[dashed] ({\myr*cos(\tdplotmainphi)},{\myr*sin(\tdplotmainphi)},0) 
  -- ({\myr*cos(\tdplotmainphi)},{\myr*sin(\tdplotmainphi)},\h)
  ({\myr*cos(\tdplotmainphi+180)},{\myr*sin(\tdplotmainphi+180)},0) 
  -- ({\myr*cos(\tdplotmainphi+180)},{\myr*sin(\tdplotmainphi+180)},\h)
  plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=0:360] ({\myr*cos(\t)},{\myr*sin(\t)},0)
  plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi+180] ({\myR*cos(\t)},{\myR*sin(\t)},0);
 \draw plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi+180]
  ({\myR*cos(\t)},{\myR*sin(\t)},\h);
 \draw[left color=gray!80,right color=gray!50,middle color=gray!30,fill
  opacity=0.6] plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi-180]
  ({\myR*cos(\t)},{\myR*sin(\t)},\h)
  -- plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=\tdplotmainphi-180:\tdplotmainphi]
  ({\myR*cos(\t)},{\myR*sin(\t)},0) -- cycle;
 \draw[left color=gray!50,right color=gray!80,middle color=gray!70,fill
  opacity=0.5] plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=0:360] ({\myR*cos(\t)},{\myR*sin(\t)},\h);
 \clip   plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=0:360]
  ({\myR*cos(\t)},{\myR*sin(\t)},\h);
 \draw[left color=gray!80,right color=gray!50,middle color=gray!30]
  plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi-180] 
  ({\myr*cos(\t)},{\myr*sin(\t)},\h)
  -- plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=\tdplotmainphi-180:\tdplotmainphi]
  ({\myr*cos(\t)},{\myr*sin(\t)},0) -- cycle;
 \draw[left color=gray!30,right color=gray!50,middle color=gray!80] plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=0:360] ({\myr*cos(\t)},{\myr*sin(\t)},\h); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass[border=1mm,12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\begin{document}
\def\myr{1.5}
\def\myR{3}
\def\h{5}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{80}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=1,line cap=butt,line join=round]
 \path[fill=gray!40,even odd rule]
  plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=0:360] ({\myr*cos(\t)},{\myr*sin(\t)},0)
  plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=0:360] ({\myR*cos(\t)},{\myR*sin(\t)},0);
 \draw[dashed] ({\myr*cos(\tdplotmainphi)},{\myr*sin(\tdplotmainphi)},0) 
  -- ({\myr*cos(\tdplotmainphi)},{\myr*sin(\tdplotmainphi)},\h)
  ({\myr*cos(\tdplotmainphi+180)},{\myr*sin(\tdplotmainphi+180)},0) 
  -- ({\myr*cos(\tdplotmainphi+180)},{\myr*sin(\tdplotmainphi+180)},\h)
  plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi+180] ({\myR*cos(\t)},{\myR*sin(\t)},0);
 \draw[dashed,fill=gray!20] plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=0:360]
 ({\myr*cos(\t)},{\myr*sin(\t)},0);
 \draw plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi+180]
  ({\myR*cos(\t)},{\myR*sin(\t)},\h);
 \draw[left color=gray!80,right color=gray!50,middle color=gray!20,fill
  opacity=0.6] plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi-180]
  ({\myR*cos(\t)},{\myR*sin(\t)},\h)
  -- plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=\tdplotmainphi-180:\tdplotmainphi]
  ({\myR*cos(\t)},{\myR*sin(\t)},0) -- cycle;
 \draw[fill=gray!90,fill opacity=0.6] plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=0:360] ({\myR*cos(\t)},{\myR*sin(\t)},\h);
 \draw[left color=gray!30,right color=gray!50,middle color=gray!20] plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=0:360] ({\myr*cos(\t)},{\myr*sin(\t)},\h); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As is well known, such cylinders are used by koalas for parachuting. The koala is taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448599/194703). The following code has some annotations and allows us to have something inside the cylinder.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm,12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\newsavebox\Koala
\sbox\Koala{\tikz[scale=0.2]{
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=koala]
\koala
\end{scope}
\foreach \X in {135,120,...,45}
{\draw (koala.\X) -- ++ (\X:1);}
\shade[ball color=blue,opacity=0.4] ($(koala.45)+(45:1)$) to[bend right=35] ($(koala.135)+(135:1)$)
to[out=90,in=90,looseness=2] cycle;}}
\begin{document}
\def\myr{1.5}
\def\myR{3}
\def\h{5}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{80}
\foreach \n in {0,1,...,20}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=1,line cap=butt,line join=round]
 \path[tdplot_screen_coords,use as bounding box] (-1.1*\myR,-0.4*\myR) rectangle
 (1.1*\myR,0.4*\myR+\h);
 % lower ring
 \path[fill=gray!40,even odd rule]
  plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=0:360] ({\myr*cos(\t)},{\myr*sin(\t)},0)
  plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=0:360] ({\myR*cos(\t)},{\myR*sin(\t)},0);
 % dashed inner contours 
 \draw[dashed] ({\myr*cos(\tdplotmainphi)},{\myr*sin(\tdplotmainphi)},0) 
  -- ({\myr*cos(\tdplotmainphi)},{\myr*sin(\tdplotmainphi)},\h)
  ({\myr*cos(\tdplotmainphi+180)},{\myr*sin(\tdplotmainphi+180)},0) 
  -- ({\myr*cos(\tdplotmainphi+180)},{\myr*sin(\tdplotmainphi+180)},\h)
  plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi+180] ({\myR*cos(\t)},{\myR*sin(\t)},0);
 % lower inner circle
 \draw[dashed,fill=gray!20] plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=0:360]
 ({\myr*cos(\t)},{\myr*sin(\t)},0);
 % upper outer contour in the back
 \draw plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi+180]
  ({\myR*cos(\t)},{\myR*sin(\t)},\h);
 % upper hole 
 \draw[left color=gray!30,right color=gray!50,middle color=gray!20] plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=0:360] ({\myr*cos(\t)},{\myr*sin(\t)},\h); 
 % upper ring in the back 
 \draw[fill=gray!90,fill opacity=0.6,even odd rule] 
  plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi+180] 
  ({\myR*cos(\t)},{\myR*sin(\t)},\h)  
  plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=\tdplotmainphi+180:\tdplotmainphi] 
  ({\myr*cos(\t)},{\myr*sin(\t)},\h);
 % koala
 \path[postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position
        \n/20 with {\node[rotate={30*sin(\n*36)}]{\usebox\Koala};}}] 
        plot[variable=\x,domain=0:720,samples=72] 
        ({0.2*sin(\x)},0,{1.2*\h-\h*\n/20});
 %  upper ring in the front      
 \draw[fill=gray!90,fill opacity=0.6,even odd rule] 
 plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi-180] 
 ({\myR*cos(\t)},{\myR*sin(\t)},\h)  
 plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=\tdplotmainphi-180:\tdplotmainphi] 
 ({\myr*cos(\t)},{\myr*sin(\t)},\h);
 % front
 \draw[left color=gray!80,right color=gray!50,middle color=gray!20,fill
  opacity=0.6] plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi-180]
  ({\myR*cos(\t)},{\myR*sin(\t)},\h)
  -- plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=\tdplotmainphi-180:\tdplotmainphi]
  ({\myR*cos(\t)},{\myR*sin(\t)},0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No. I don't want to fill inside of small cylinder.

Comment: @ThuyNguyen Better now?

Comment: @ThuyNguyen Sorry, I do not understand the request.

Comment: Amazing answer. One more refinement would be perfect: the small circle at the bottom may need lighter shade than its surrounding ring.